# Prove that there's no order in the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Problem:

Let $p$ be a prime and $\Bbb{Z}_p$ be the set of residue classes modulo $p$. Prove that no matter what proposed ordering is assigned to the finite field, one of the 4 ordering axioms will fail. Thus, it is not possible to order the field's elements in any way.

My solution:

Let $\overline{a} \in \Bbb{Z}_p$ and the residue class $\overline{a}$ corresponds to the value $a \in \Bbb{Z}:a>0$

The sum of two strictly positive elements should be strictly positive

Let $b = p - a$. Because $0<a<p$ we have $a<p \implies 0<p-a$

Thus: $\overline{a}+\overline{p-a} = (a+(p-a))\mod{p} = p\mod{p}=0$

Thus we have: $\overline{a}+\overline{b} = \overline{a}+\overline{p-a} = \overline{0}$ but $0 < a$

Thus, by contradiction, the set's elements cannot be ordered.

Is this right? Thanks :)

Comment: Why is it in $\mathbb Z_p$ that *The sum of two strictly positive elements should be strictly positive*?

Comment: They are not. I am assuming it behaves like in the real numbers.